Third Monitor suddenly stopped working Arch Linux
I have 3 monitors on my pc. I run Arch linux with the 6.11.6-arch1-1 kernel. I installed linux-headers. They are on the newest version. When i type hyprctl monitors, it shows the third monitor output as DVI-D-1, also it shows properties and characteristics of the third monitor, just that my monitor isn't getting a signal. The problem just happened from one day to the next, without me doing any major changes to the kernel. I just configured waybar, but that shouldn't impact my monitors. Well, I am also pretty sure, that there is no problem with the physical connection.
EDIT: The monitor is connected to my GPU over the DVI port, i just saw in another forum, that that port causes issues with nvidia drivers, so I will look into that.
